# How do I copy a download link if it doesn't appear in a right click?

Tags: html

If you hit "Download" a new bar appears and gives you the options: "1080p, 720p, 480p, 320p". **I am trying to copy the link for 1080p.**

If you left click on 1080p it starts downloading regularly. If you right click on 1080p it's as if you right clicked anywhere on the page.

Here is what it looks like.
[image: Here is what it looks like.]

I opened up developer tools and looked thru the Elements & Network tabs but I cannot find any links.

This is what Elements looks like.
[image: This is what Elements looks like.]

Once you actually hit 1080p a link appears but it disappears.

This is what the url looks like.
[image: This is what the url looks like.]

Can someone explain how I would capture this link?

Comment: This looks like it is a Javascript-enabled button. Use inspect element to see what it is firing.

Comment: @Saddy fam I right clicked the download button, hit inspect, elements, and already posted the screenshot above. Can you let me know what "inspect element" is? I don't see a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there is a (java)script which will be triggered if you click on that button which downloads that video. A way to (among other things) prevent what you are trying to do...

Comment: So there is no way around this?